# NSDate with Core Data formatted for localization

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I need to save the date with Core Data and when user selects a certain part of the app, the date shows in their localized format (e.g.
 Chinese or French).

If I do this `[NSDate date]` if I'm not mistaken gives me the date in GMT.

If I want to save to Core Data do I set as so?

```
[objectToSave setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"date"];
```

Or do I have to set it with the locale? How do I do this?

Or do I just set the date as above and then format the locale when I remake my model object after retrieving from Core Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the whole purpose of `NSDate`.  It gives you a universal date value that can then be interpreted in whatever locale you desire.

Really, unless there is a very, very good reason, you should always store dates this way.

You only need to localize it when presenting the data, usually on screen.  You do that by getting the current local of the user.

This way, if both of us use the same data, I can see it in Hebrew and you can see it in French, and our timezones could be Jerusalem and Paris.

We would see the exact same time, but in our own locale format and local timezone, without doing any conversions of the data on our own.